# Android 8 - Register two different services with filter com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, push, phonegap

I have the following configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml file from an apache cordova hybrid app:

```
    </application>
...
    <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.FCMService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="my.custom.CustomNotificationsListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

All was working properly until android 8 where only one Service listener is triggered. If I remove one of them, the other catches the received notification as expected.

One of them, is generated by the phonegap plugin and the other is intended to treat the notification and do some stuff in background.

It's like just one of them catches and consumes the notification and does not propagate to others listeners.

Is there any way to keep these differents listeners working together in Android 8?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could try scheduling a job from one of the broadcast receivers that will do the same thing the second receiver is supposed to do. That way, you won't have to register two listeners for the same event.